# Mail of PHP, DNS request timed out, and FQDN

Tags: dns, smtp, windows-server-2012-r2, nslookup, fqdn

I want to make `mail()` of PHP work in my `Windows Server 2012 R2`. To this end, I first installed `SMTP` by following [this page](http://www.vsysad.com/2014/09/setup-and-configure-smtp-server-on-windows-server-2012/).

One thing that confuses me is the `Full-qualified domain name`. `WIN-RFELH8GM0KN` is what it proposes by default. My server hosts several websites, does anyone know which website I should specify here?

I did not change this, as a consequence, `mail www.google.com` in `nslookup` returns `DNS request timed out.` So is it an error?

[image]

Of cause, my `test.php` does not send the mail:

```
<?php
mail('mymail@gmail.com', 'title', 'content');
?>
```

Could anyone help?

**Update 1** Following the answer of @LittleAI , I started SMTP, but `DNS request timed out` is still there:

[image]

**Update 2** Here is `php.ini`:

[image]

`telnet localhost 25` returns the follows:

[image]

**Update 3** Here was a test, which worked well: I did receive the test mail in the inbox of `softtitmur@gmail.com`. However, if I redo the test in `Update 1`, there is still `DNS requested time out.`. And `test.php` still cannot send the mail...

[image]

**Update 4** I just realised that in [the page I followed](http://www.vsysad.com/2014/09/setup-and-configure-smtp-server-on-windows-server-2012/), it is `mail.vsysad.com` under `nslookup` (I thought it was `mail vsysad.com`, that is why i tried `mail www.google.com` which did not make sense). So it works also in my server, and there is no `DNS request timed out`.

[image]

Then, I double checked `php.ini`, I realised that `sendmail_from` was not uncommented. So **I uncommented it and set `sendmail_from = softtimur@gmail.com`**, as a result, `mail()` of php works now, so the problem is solved, though I still don't understand FQDN and its default value (ie, `WIN-RFELH8GM0KN`)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I noticed is that your SMTP Virtual service in IIS is not in a starting state so this would cause an issue. Make sure this service is in a starting state before testing.

The FQDN name is mainly used for the SMTP banner which the sender will be presented when connecting over port 25 to your server.

It maybe worth installing the DNS role onto your server and create a forward lookup zone referencing a fake domain e.g test.com and create an a record within this zone called SMTP using your servers IP. Make sure to then set your server to use 127.0.0.1 as the DNS provider so it can check record before delegating the reponse to root hints/external dns forwarder.

You need to do an SMTP request using Telnet to confirm SMTP is listening on port 25. You can do this by using the localhost ip address (127.0.0.1) as shown below:

```
  telnet 127.0.0.1 25
  helo test.com
  MAIL FROM: ****YOUR EMAIL ACCOUNT****
  RCPT TO: ****SENDERS ADDRESS****
  DATA
```

You would probably not receive the email from your relay to GMAIL due to SPF Record which is in place that only allows certain IP/hostnames to send as google.com, but for testing you should see your server receive the mail after data has been inputted.

Here is the guide for using telnet on your server. Just make sure you have telnet feature installed as this is not installed by default.

http://www.yuki-onna.co.uk/email/smtp.html

**Additional:**

```
 telnet localhost 25
```

After the SMTP banner type the following command in but make sure not to make any mistakes or else you'll need to probably start your sesssion all over again.

```
 helo test.com
```

You should then see a 250 response to say the server is listening

The type the following:

```
MAIL FROM: test@test.com
```

It should respond with OK. If so, then type:

```
RCPT TO: ***YOU EMAIL ADDRESS OF CHOICE****
```

Again, it should respond with OK. If so, type the following:

```
DATA
```

Press enter after the DATA command. Your now into the body of the email. For testing purposes we will miss the subject bar and just add some data to the body.

```
  This is a test email.
```

Then to complete the email you need to leave a blank line by pressing return, then a full stop, then return again like so.

```
    ***BLANK LINE****
    .
    ***Hit Return****
```

Screenshot all the commands but you can blank out the email so I can see the output.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the part except starting SMTP is really hard to understand. I started the SMTP but the error is still there (please see the update in the OP). I just want to make `mail` of `php` work, could you tell me the mandatory steps to realise this?

Comment: I'll help and I'm sure we will get this sorted. Can you confirm if your PHP.ini settings on your windows server are configured to use localhost. [How to configure PHP SMTP mail settings Link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php)

Comment: Can you also confirm if the server is listening on port 25? You can do this by typing the following command  in command prompt 'telnet localhost 25'

Comment: Okay thats good, I can see the SMTP banner which is the same as the Fully Qualified Domain Name and it's accepting requests on 25 which is perfect. If possible, can you test that mail is sending via telnet? You can do this from CMD or Powershell (which I can see that your using). Type in the following:

Comment: See my answer for steps to test.

Comment: Please see my update... Btw, should I install DNS server?

Comment: Thats good news. We understand that SMTP is accepting requests from localhost on port 25 so there is not an issue with your relay. The issue seems to be with your WAMP or XAMPP setup. Can you confirm what PHP software you are using for hosting PHP. With regards to your NSLOOKUP in powershell, what are you trying to achieve by typing in 'mail www.google.com' ? Also, no need to install DNS server role as your server is working fine and able to resolve external requests. I know this because your email would not of send to gmail without doing some form of MX lookup (DNS Query for mail).

Comment: Please see my update... So the key is to not forget to set `sendmail_from` to make `mail()` work. Thanks for your help, which let me know how to use `telnet` to test SMTP...

Comment: Great news! I'm glad its working for you and thanks for sharing the exact fix.